# Parallel Computation of the Number π using OpenMP

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm using the following code in order to parallelize the computation of π.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define N 1000000 // Number of intervals for integration

double calculate_pi_parallel_trapezoidal() {
    double integral = 0.0;
    double dx = 1.0 / N;

    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:integral)
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        double x = (i + 0.5) * dx;
        double fx = sqrt(1.0 - x * x);
        integral += fx * dx;
    }

    return 4.0 * integral;
}

int main() {
    double pi;
    double start_time, end_time;
    int num_threads;

    // Set the environment variable to control thread affinity
    setenv("GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY", "0-7", 1);

    // Get the maximum number of threads available
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp master
        {
            num_threads = omp_get_max_threads();
        }
    }
    printf("Maximum number of threads: %d\n", num_threads);

    // Experiment with different numbers of threads
    for (int threads = 1; threads <= num_threads; threads++) {
        // Set the number of threads using the environment variable
        omp_set_num_threads(threads);

        start_time = omp_get_wtime(); // Record the start time

        pi = calculate_pi_parallel_trapezoidal();

        end_time = omp_get_wtime(); // Record the end time

        printf("Threads: %d, Approximation of Pi (Trapezoidal Rule): %.16f, Time taken: %f seconds\n", threads, pi, end_time - start_time);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I use OpenMP API for this problem as you can see in the code snippet above. The command-line to compile the code is `gcc -fopenmp -O3 pi.c -o pi -lm` , `03` for highest optimization possible and `-lm` to link the `libm` (math) library since I'm using `sqrt`. Then I simply run the code using `./pi`.
The results of the execution of the above code is the following:

```
Maximum number of threads: 8
Threads: 1, Approximation of Pi (Trapezoidal Rule): 3.1415926539343633, Time taken: 0.006868 seconds
Threads: 2, Approximation of Pi (Trapezoidal Rule): 3.1415926539341976, Time taken: 0.003119 seconds
Threads: 3, Approximation of Pi (Trapezoidal Rule): 3.1415926539342567, Time taken: 0.001779 seconds
Threads: 4, Approximation of Pi (Trapezoidal Rule): 3.1415926539342074, Time taken: 0.001705 seconds
Threads: 5, Approximation of Pi (Trapezoidal Rule): 3.1415926539342571, Time taken: 0.001142 seconds
Threads: 6, Approximation of Pi (Trapezoidal Rule): 3.1415926539342460, Time taken: 0.000825 seconds
Threads: 7, Approximation of Pi (Trapezoidal Rule): 3.1415926539342056, Time taken: 0.001365 seconds
Threads: 8, Approximation of Pi (Trapezoidal Rule): 3.1415926539342003, Time taken: 0.019961 seconds
```

Interestingly enough every time I run the code I get different results

```
Maximum number of threads: 8
Threads: 1, Approximation of Pi (Trapezoidal Rule): 3.1415926539343633, Time taken: 0.005567 seconds
Threads: 2, Approximation of Pi (Trapezoidal Rule): 3.1415926539341976, Time taken: 0.002621 seconds
Threads: 3, Approximation of Pi (Trapezoidal Rule): 3.1415926539342571, Time taken: 0.003349 seconds
Threads: 4, Approximation of Pi (Trapezoidal Rule): 3.1415926539342074, Time taken: 0.001916 seconds
Threads: 5, Approximation of Pi (Trapezoidal Rule): 3.1415926539342571, Time taken: 0.001457 seconds
Threads: 6, Approximation of Pi (Trapezoidal Rule): 3.1415926539342460, Time taken: 0.000927 seconds
Threads: 7, Approximation of Pi (Trapezoidal Rule): 3.1415926539342056, Time taken: 0.000866 seconds
Threads: 8, Approximation of Pi (Trapezoidal Rule): 3.1415926539342007, Time taken: 0.019658 seconds
```

I don't know the reason for this but I have a feeling it's normal, am I wrong?

As you may understand I have 8 logical processors (threads), and 4 physical cores (two threads per core). I run the code on an ubuntu 22.04.

Now the question is even though I have 8 threads and I run the code on 8 threads the run time doesn't decrease  as the number of threads decrease all the way to the highest number os threads used and from the seven threads, the run time increases again! From what I understood I shouldn't expect this behavior and the run time should decrease all the way to the highest threads used, given that I have 8 threads and I use all 8 threads to parallelize.

I read different reasons for such issue, such as, load balancing, overhead, thread affinity, etc. but I have no idea how to diagnose what the problem is and how to fix it, could you please chip in and suggest your theories and tips on how I can resolve the issue and at the same time learn more about the multithreading and parallelization?

**UPDATE**

I made some adjustment to `N` based on some of the tips given in the comments, I increase `N` from `10E06` to `10E09` and I get the following results:

```
Maximum number of threads: 8
Threads: 1, Approximation of Pi (Trapezoidal Rule): 3.1415926535902123, Time taken: 1.379732 seconds
Threads: 2, Approximation of Pi (Trapezoidal Rule): 3.1415926535901511, Time taken: 0.746554 seconds
Threads: 3, Approximation of Pi (Trapezoidal Rule): 3.1415926535899734, Time taken: 0.518842 seconds
Threads: 4, Approximation of Pi (Trapezoidal Rule): 3.1415926535898255, Time taken: 0.414103 seconds
Threads: 5, Approximation of Pi (Trapezoidal Rule): 3.1415926535899268, Time taken: 0.518961 seconds
Threads: 6, Approximation of Pi (Trapezoidal Rule): 3.1415926535899241, Time taken: 0.490220 seconds
Threads: 7, Approximation of Pi (Trapezoidal Rule): 3.1415926535897527, Time taken: 0.443656 seconds
Threads: 8, Approximation of Pi (Trapezoidal Rule): 3.1415926535899521, Time taken: 0.413821 seconds
```

So based on some of the suggestions in the comments since OpenMP only scale up to the number of physical cores (as suggested by some fellow members, see in the comments) as I only have 4 physical cores the run time should decrease up to four cores at a time, as it can be seen in the results above, then when we move to 5 threads (logical cores) there is a jump in the run time and from there it decreases again.

Would somebody explain this phenomenon please?

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Logical theads will have to share the physical cores, so only 4 of them can run at any time. Works fine if the threads have to wait for input, but not if they all do intense computations.

Comment: @BoP OS Threads are for waiting on IO. For hardware threads, the primary things that allow sharing are memory latency and having diverse operations, so one thread can use one execution unit whilst the other uses a different execution unit. Unfortunately this code is a tight loop with no memory dependency, and no diversity of instructions. So logical cores won't help here.

Comment: Don't use the `setenv`: set `OMP_PROC_BIND=true` in your environment. That's the official mechanism, and while you can be more precise, this is usually enough.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout , Wow I can't believe Victor Eijkhout commented on my question. Thanks for your feedback Victor. Just to clarify, what you mean is that I need to set OMP_PROC_BIND=true to my environment and get rid of setenv("GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY", "0-7", 1); and it would solve my problem?

Comment: @Dude, Computation tip: `#define N 1000000` injects an immediate round-off error in `double dx = 1.0 / N;`.  Consider instead, powers of 2 like `#define N 1024L*1024` for a small numeric improvement.  `1.0 - x * x` --> `(1.0 - x)*(1.0 + x)` may help a tad too.

Comment: The command-line to compile and run the program is unfortunately not provided. This is critical in all performance-related questions, and especially this one. Instructions generated by the compiler (dependent of the user compilation flags) can have a strong impact on the observed performance, especially when using more threads than cores on CPUs supporting SMT. This is also critical to know which OpenMP back-end is used and also know if optimizations are enabled. Please add this information as an update. Please also share the exact CPU used to run the program (the architecture matters a lot).

Comment: I get different (conflicting) results with different compilers (Clang and GCC, on a testing machine) which tend to prove how important this is. Same with `-O1` vs `-O3` which impacts the observed behaviour. Note the compiler version matters a bit too.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, Thanks for your comments Jérôme, I enriched the post with more information.

Comment: With a larger `N` you would have more stable runtimes between runs

Comment: My comment was about avoiding compiler-specific options and using the standard mechanism. Your actual problem was pointed out by @BoP : OpenMP usually only scales to the physical core count; logical processors will not help you in this sort of computation.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information, but the processor reference is still missing (and the GCC version). The most important information is the processor architecture. And yes, `N` is indeed pretty small : a benchmark lasting 1 ms is generally not reliable. I expect short-running code to be more accelerated by frequency boosts (especially on notebooks due to a possible power throttling). Not to mention the time to create and schedule threads can introduce some performance instabilities at this scale.

Comment: I am still not able to reproduce this so far (on all GCC versions between GCC 5 and GCC 13 except maybe on GCC 6.xx and 8.xx for some weird reasons). Besides, Is the effect still observable with the compilation flag `-Wa,-mbranches-within-32B-boundaries` ?

Comment: Thank you all for all the interesting eye opening comments, as you might have guessed I'm still learning about parallel programming so there are lots of materials in your comments for me that are new for me and help me to learn more. @JérômeRichard , the GCC version I'm using is `gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0` and my processor is `11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz × 8`, hope this helps. Thanks again Jérôme for following up with my problem.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout So if I understood from your comment my code is correct from a technical point of view but I only can expect to see a decrease in run time up to 4 physical cores? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @BoP Thank you for your comment, if you notice I updated the post with some new information. So what you and Victor Eijkhout are saying is that I can't expect to see a decrease in run time up to 4 physical cores? Based on the new information I provided how can I explain the new results?

Comment: Your lastest results with a large N are fully consistent with what is explained to you, i.e. that for this kind of computations the logical cores do not help.

Comment: @PierU Thanks for the follow up, would you kindly suggest some references (keywords, links, etc.) regarding such specific problem so I could go read and learn more about it please? The information in the comments are quite abstract I need to read more about it.

Comment: Note 10E09 is too big to fit in a signed integer (on GCC, ints are typically stored in 4 bytes so the maximum value is about 2e9). You should use a `long` or even a `int64_t` for `i` to be large enough (it may also impact a bit the execution time).

Comment: Using SMT, that is more threads than cores, can actually be faster in some cases, even computational ones like this, but not in this specific example. There is no general high level rule. This is very hard to know since it is dependent of the assembly code generated by the compiler (so the C code) and the processor architecture (and possibly other things like the RAM), hence my previous comments. One can estimate the performance based on how modern processors works and tools but this is far from being trivial to do for beginners and it require a deep understanding on how processors operate.

Comment: In this specific case, GCC 11.4 generate an assembly code which is bound by the throughput of the execution ports of your Tiger Lake processor. This means the code cannot benefit from using more threads than cores because the execution ports are already saturated. This matches with the observed results (though the integer overflow may cause the benchmark to be biased since it is AFAIK undefined behaviour).

Comment: If you compile the same code with GCC 8.4, then the assembly code is bound by the latency of generated instructions on your processor. The code should thus be significantly slower, but it should also be faster with 8 threads than 4 threads (as opposed to current results). This is because of dependencies issues in the generated code. Low-level details matters a lot for SMT performance. I think it is better for beginners to use 1 thread per core (and keep the possibility to change the number of threads thanks to the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` variable so users can do tests on their own platform).

Comment: Some keywords are "hyperthreading", "context switch"...

Comment: I forgot to mention that using `-ffast-math` should significantly speed up this code (thanks to SIMD instruction which cannot be used by default due to the floating-point associativity limitation). It might have an impact on SMT performance (but I expect the same effects overall on your platform).

Comment: @JérômeRichard, thanks a bunch for all the useful information, i'm just reading on google about the information you provided, but since the information are really technical  and new for me it takes me some time to keep up with the conversation :)

Answer (score 1):

About logical cores and why using them does not necessarily speed-up computations (thanks to Jérôme Richard who corrected my initial answer)

First consider a CPU with N physical cores, and a program that runs with N threads. The OS is responsible for scheduling the threads on the cores. For simplicity let's imagine no other thread is running, so in practice the OS can leave each thread on a core indefinitely.

As long as each core receives the instructions and data fast enough from the memory, this is all good: the code is said to be "CPU bound" (performances are limited only by the CPU) and it scales perfectly with more cores/threads (the speed-up in terms of elapsed time is N).

Now, if each core does not receive data fast enough (because the bandwidth between RAM and CPU is limited) then it gets regularly idle, and the code is said to be "memory bound". The speed-up is (sometimes much) less than N and is bounded by the bandwith. This is nicely illustrated on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77921645/14778592).

Once a core gets idle, the OS scheduler removes the current thread from the core and replaces it with another thread (it switches the threads), which hopefully has enough data ready to use to make the core busy. One problem is that switching the threads comes at a cost: the OS has to save the state of the thread (e.g. the registers) that was on the core, and restore the state of the thread that replaces it. During this, the core does not perform useful computations.

Here come the logical cores (technique known as Simultaneous MultiThreading (SMT), or hyperthreading in Intel): each physical core is viewed by the OS as 2 cores, so the OS can schedule 2 simultaneous threads on it. The core still has a unique intruction pipe, but it can interleave instructions from both threads, and each thread has its own "context" (e.g. there are 2 sets of registers). If thread gets idle, the core may be still busy with the other thread.

So it can be tempting to run as many threads as logical cores (2*N) in order to keep the physical cores constantly busy, but actually this is not necessarily a win situation:

- if the code is purely CPU bound, running more than N threads does not help because the physical core are already fully busy with N threads
- if the code is purely memory-bound, running more than N threads doesn't help either (*) because at the end the bottleneck is the bandwith: the threads will be interleaved on the cores, but each one will receive twice as less data and will be active twice as less time.
- the only case where it can help is if the different threads are not all CPU-bound or memory-bound at the same time

(*) this can even hurt instead of helping, because more threads often means more random accesses to the memory, hence more cache misses. This very visible on the performance curves of the other answer.

It may sound a bit restrictive, but actually the logical cores are useful anyway because the OS can schedule the threads from the processes other than your main compute process (that is, mostly system processes in a HPC context) without necessarily having to switch your computing threads.

Comment: Here I am to bring some correction ;) ! The situation where the memory throughput is the limiting factor is actually not a good use-case for SMT (i.e. it should not be faster with more threads). Using more thread will not solve the saturation of the memory. In fact, this is quite the opposite which is often seen : having more RAM request from more threads tends to cause more random accesses which are less efficient (due to the RAM latency, the way DDR-X SDRAM work and certainly the CPU IMC too not to mention possibly CPU offcore prefetchers if any).

Comment: If the code is memory-bound due to the latency of the L3 cache or DRAM latency, then SMT can speed things up. I think a good example should be a naive transposition. Note that the speed up of using 2 threads per core should not be as big as 2x since SMT threads share resources (L1+L2 cache and certainly load/store entries too) and it seems not so easy to mitigate the latency of the DDR-X SDRAM with many requests (due to the way they internally operate). Besides, benchmarks on Intel CPUs show they can tune the prefetching based on the access pattern and the number of pending requests.

Comment: Note that "hyper-threading" is the name of the Intel implementation of the SMT technique. SMT is the academic vendor-independent term ;) .

Comment: *"Still this is a single physical core, which can execute only one thread at a time..."* This is wrong. Modern Intel (starting from Haswell) and AMD (Zen) processors can run 2 threads on 2 logical cores fully in parallel regarding the target code. I started to write a long answer explaining how it works but I actually proved that SMT was not beneficial in the specific case of the OP so the explanation was not much useful. Hence the last comments below the OP question. https://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/ explain how things work pretty well.

Comment: The reason SMT should not be beneficial in the OP code (with the specific compiler and compilation flags on the specific target CPU) is that the execution ports are already saturated. Thus, more threads cannot help to saturate more the execution ports (but they introduce overheads). It can with GCC 8.4 for example due to a very different generated assembly code which is latency bound.

Comment: The conversation has become very interesting for me, I'm gaining some very new understanding about parallel programming, and I should admit it's way more intricate than what I assumed. I am still going through different resources trying to gain a better understanding of what has been said so far and it's very much possible that I'll be back with new questions. I believe it's become a very interesting exchange of ideas, thanks again for your rich contribution.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thaks for the corrections, I will update the answer. Indeed I had in mind a case I encountered where the threads were alternatively CPU-bound and memory-bound in different parts of the code, so there was some benefit using more threads than cores"... But yeah, I agree that a code that is only one or the other won't benefit from SMT.

Comment: Also, when saying that *"a single physical core[...] can execute only one thread at a time"* I was meaning that the ALU's were not duplicated, which does not prevent the pipe containing instructions from both threads simultaneous. But I thought that the core had to perform some context switch between the 2 threads, and it seems that this is not the case?

Comment: Actually being able to have instructions from 2 different threads in the pipe requires to have the contexts of both threads simultaneously available, so I understand that context switching makes no sense here...

Comment: @PierU Yes, the threads are scheduled by the OS on hardware-threads / logical-cores (as opposed to physical cores). The OS mainly see just more (logical) cores on which software threads needs to be scheduled. Not much more. At the CPU level, a thread is basically a stack/base pointer, a code pointer and some GPR (+ a static/dynamic partitioning of some low-level resources to ensure an isolation tough SMT as a lot of security vulnerabilities showing the lack of isolation).

Comment: @PierU The CPU front-end fetch/decode instructions the two active threads and AFAIK the backend does not care much what thread execute what instruction. It just receive a flow of (micro-)instructions to execute. Context-switches are controlled by the OS (though they can be triggered by interrupts causing an OS routine to be called). While CPUs partially help the OS to do this job, this is clearly not done in-silico yet. Besides, the overhead of a context switch is so huge (at least several hundreds of cycles -- often >1000) that it would defeat the purpose of doing that at a fine granularity.

Comment: @PierU Note that CPUs have no information about ready threads or inactive threads. They are only aware of scheduled thread on the current socket. Also note that a significant part of the context-switch overhead is due to CPUs themselves : many resources needs to be reset/flushed (e.g. GPR, SIMD registers, cache prediction buffers, TLB cache, process informations, possibly even the L1 in some cases) and reloaded (many cache misses are due to the TLB flush).