# OpenMP-based loop with reduction scales poorly

Tags: c++, openmp, performance-testing, benchmarking, parallelism-amdahl

I have a loop which I'm trying to efficiently parallelize with OpenMP. It involves accumulating the L2 norm of a vector stream, which comes with a reduction. Here's the loop:

```
struct vec3
{
    float data[3] = {};
};

float accumulate_eta_sq_t_mass(const vec3* etas, const float* masses, const std::size_t& n)
{
    auto a = 0.0;
    #pragma omp parallel for simd safelen(16) reduction(+:a)
    for (auto ii = std::size_t{}; ii < n; ++ii)
    {
        const auto& eta = etas[ii];
        const auto x = static_cast<double>(eta.data[0]);
        const auto y = static_cast<double>(eta.data[1]);
        const auto z = static_cast<double>(eta.data[2]);
        const auto m = static_cast<double>(masses[ii]);
        
        a += (x * x + y * y + z * z) * m;
    }
    
    return static_cast<float>(a);
}
```

I wrote a micro-benchmarking program (code provided in the appendix) which shows that the simple loop does not scale very well as seen in the following diagram.

[image]

Here we're seeing a serial fraction of 15% according to Amdahl's law. In your experience (or perhaps in theory), is it normal for OpenMP loops with a reduction clause to scale so unimpressively? I can provide more information if needed. Thanks in advance.

**Note:** I'm using double precision in the loop to reduce large rounding errors in the accumulation. Using single precision did not lead to any improvement in scaling performance.

---

**Additional information**

@paleonix This was run on the Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8400 CPU @ 2.80GHz with 6 cores (no SMT) with cache sizes 192 KiB, 1.5 MiB and 9 MiB and highest vector flag AVX2.

---

**Appendix**

Here's the minimum reproducer which should compile so `g++ -O3 -march=native -ffast-math -std=c++17 -fopenmp ./min_rep.cpp -o min_rep`. It is to be called with a sufficiently large size, in my case 10000000.

```
/// \file This file contains a micro-benchmark program for the SAXPY loop.

#include <string> // std::stoul
#include <utility> // std::abort
#include <iostream> // std::cerr
#include <cstdint> // std::uint64_t
#include <algorithm> // std::min
#include <limits> // std::numeric_limits
#include <vector> // std::vector

#include <omp.h>

#include <stdlib.h> // posix_memalign
#include <unistd.h> // sysconf

struct vec3
{
    float data[3] = {};
};

float accumulate_eta_sq_t_mass(const vec3* etas, const float* masses, const std::size_t& n)
{
    auto a = 0.0;
    #pragma omp parallel for simd safelen(16) reduction(+:a)
    for (auto ii = std::size_t{}; ii < n; ++ii)
    {
        const auto& eta = etas[ii];
        const auto x = static_cast<double>(eta.data[0]);
        const auto y = static_cast<double>(eta.data[1]);
        const auto z = static_cast<double>(eta.data[2]);
        const auto m = static_cast<double>(masses[ii]);
        
        a += (x * x + y * y + z * z) * m;
    }
    
    return static_cast<float>(a);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // extract the problem size
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        std::cerr << "Please provide the problem size as command line argument." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    const auto n = static_cast<std::size_t>(std::stoul(argv[1]));
    if (n < 1)
    {
        std::cerr << "Zero valued problem size provided. The program will now be aborted." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    if (n * sizeof(float) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) > 40) // let's assume there's only 64 GiB of RAM
    {
        std::cerr << "Problem size is too large. The program will now be aborted." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    
    // report
    std::cout << "Starting runs with problem size n=" << n << ".\nThread count: " << omp_get_max_threads() << "."
        << std::endl;
    
    // details
    const auto page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
    const auto page_size_vec3 = page_size / sizeof(vec3);
    const auto page_size_float = page_size / sizeof(float);
    
    // experiment loop
    const auto experiment_count = 50;
    const auto warm_up_count = 10;
    const auto run_count = experiment_count + warm_up_count;
    auto durations = std::vector(experiment_count, std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::min());
    
    vec3* etas = nullptr;
    float* masses = nullptr;
    for (auto run_index = std::size_t{}; run_index < run_count; ++run_index)
    {
        // allocate
        const auto alloc_status0 = posix_memalign(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&etas), page_size, n * sizeof(vec3));
        const auto alloc_status1 = posix_memalign(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&masses), page_size, n * sizeof(float));
        if (alloc_status0 != 0 || alloc_status1 != 0 || etas == nullptr || masses == nullptr)
        {
            std::cerr << "Fatal error, failed to allocate memory." << std::endl;
            std::abort();
        }
        
        // "first touch"
        #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
        for (auto ii = std::size_t{}; ii < n; ii += page_size_vec3)
        {
            etas[ii].data[0] = 0.f;
        }
        #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
        for (auto ii = std::size_t{}; ii < n; ii += page_size_float)
        {
            masses[ii] = 0.f;
        }
        
        // run experiment
        const auto t1 = omp_get_wtime();
        accumulate_eta_sq_t_mass(etas, masses, n);
        const auto t2 = omp_get_wtime();
        const auto duration_in_us = static_cast<std::int64_t>((t2 - t1) * 1E+6);
        if (duration_in_us <= 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "Fatal error, no time elapsed in the test function." << std::endl;
            std::abort();
        }
        if (run_index + 1 > warm_up_count)
        {
            durations[run_index - warm_up_count] = static_cast<std::uint64_t>(duration_in_us);
        }
        
        // deallocate
        std::free(etas);
        std::free(masses);
        etas = nullptr;
        masses = nullptr;
    }
    
    // statistics
    auto min = std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::max();
    auto max = std::uint64_t{};
    auto mean = std::uint64_t{};
    for (const auto& duration : durations)
    {
        min = std::min(min, duration);
        max = std::max(max, duration);
        mean += duration;
    }
    mean /= experiment_count;
    
    // report duration
    std::cout << "Mean duration:      " << mean << " us\n"
        << "Min. duration:      " << min << " us\n"
        << "Max. duration:      " << max << " us.\n";
    
    // compute effective B/W
    const auto traffic = 4 * n * sizeof(float);
    constexpr auto inv_gigi = 1.0 / static_cast<double>(1024 * 1024 * 1024);
    const auto traffic_in_gib = static_cast<double>(traffic) * inv_gigi;
    std::cout << "Traffic per run:    " << traffic << " B (" << traffic_in_gib << " GiB)\n" 
        << "Mean effective B/W: " << static_cast<double>(traffic_in_gib) / (static_cast<double>(mean) * 1E-6) << " GiB/s\n"
        << "Min. effective B/W: " << static_cast<double>(traffic_in_gib) / (static_cast<double>(max) * 1E-6) << " GiB/s\n"
        << "Max. effective B/W: " << static_cast<double>(traffic_in_gib) / (static_cast<double>(min) * 1E-6) << " GiB/s\n"
        << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What platform/processor was the benchmark run on? Without knowing the number of cores it is hard to interpret the results.

Comment: The `vec3` SoA structure (Struct-of-Array) is not ideal for SIMD parallelism especially with 3 floats instead of four because the `vec3` instances will generally not be well aligned. But this issue is orthogonal to the bad scaling.

Comment: @paleonix I would have guessed that the compiler (GNU compiler 11.4.0) is clever enough to eliminate that effect with permute ops. Also, would that contribute to the serial fraction in Amdahl's law?

Comment: No, even if the compiler is not able to vectorize (I would not bet on it), the unvectorized code is still executed in parallel on threads.

Comment: With hyperthreading turned off and using as many threads as cores, your threads will fight for resources with background processes/the OS. This generally adds noise to measurements but might also be the reason for the time increase with 6 threads.

Comment: small nitpick not related to the question, I really hate your use of `auto` everywhere. I mean sure, in some cases it's useful but does it really make sense to write something like `auto ii = std::size_t{}` or `auto max = std::uint64_t{}`?

Comment: @JohnDoe This is a style decision, some people like the consistency of having all types on the right. At least it gives nice alignment of all the names to the left.

Comment: @JohnDoe I tend to apply a concept as broadly as possible if it makes sense to me. It makes sense to me to define types as rarely as possible. This will mean that I, as programmer, don't have to worry about types most of the time, and changes in interfaces trickle through the implementation uniformly and with least effort. Also, as paleonix points out, I like to see my types on the right.

Comment: `reduce` adds overheads which contribute to the serial fraction but they should only scale with the number of threads and not with the loop size. So how big is `n` and what happens to the plot if you increase it significantly?

Comment: @NitinMalapally i mean, if you prefer it fair enough, it's your code after all. If you are doing work that requires precision just make sure `auto` is doing what you are actually expecting. E.G. `const auto traffic = 4 * n * sizeof(float);` on [onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com/xKWhOf4HT) is a `double` which may not be obvious and could lead to errors in the future

Comment: @JohnDoe Not sure what you are getting at, `traffic` is clearly a `size_t`. See [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/a7W1zKco3).

Comment: @paleonix Thanks for the hint about the problem size. Playing with it caused me to see something important. See answer.

Comment: @paleonix: Just for the record, GCC and clang are able to auto-vectorize this code (with `-fopenmp` or `-ffast-math`), but yes it takes a lot of shuffles and blends, and is probably barely worth it without `-march=x86-64-v3` for AVX2 (or `-march=native` on the OP's Skylake-family CPU). https://godbolt.org/z/6P4jv7jWj  GCC's SSE2 strategy seems very cumbersome vs. one packed and one scalar for each group of 3 since it also needs to convert + broadcast a multiplier from another array.

Comment: @JohnDoe: I can see the OP's point for `auto` with type on the right, except for `auto a = 0.0`. The only thing that saves that from being extremely obscure and non-obvious is the loop body that comes after it, with explicit `static_cast` to `double`, reminding the reader that `0.0` implied a type of `double`, unlike `0.0f`.  I'm also not buying it for declarations inside `for()` statements: column alignment of names doesn't apply then vs. `for(size_t ii{}` ; ...` or `for(size_t ii = 0 ; ...` which are less verbose.

Comment: @JohnDoe: `sizeof()` returns a `size_t`, but it's not a good sign for the code's readability that `auto traffic = 4 * n * sizeof(float)` had you thinking even temporarily that it was a `double`.  (Perhaps because you had `n` and `m` mixed up; the same program has an `auto m =  double` somewhere, and that `auto traffic` would be a `double` if `n` was a `double`.)  And the code is using `double` for `traffic_in_gib`.  And despite its efforts at portability like using `std::size_t` instead of `size_t`, `1024 * 1024 * 1024` would overflow on a machine with 16-bit `int`.  `1L << 30` would be safe)

Comment: *with cache sizes 192 KiB, 1.5 MiB and 9 MiB* - Your CPU has per-core private L1i/L1d (32 KiB each) and L2 (256 KiB each).  It makes little sense to add them together across cores the way we do for slices of the shared L3, although I guess for a problem like this where each worker thread only touches part of the array, it could lead to cache hits if you ran the same small reduction repeatedly and the same worker threads got assigned the same chunks of the array.

Comment: *i5-8400 CPU @ 2.80GHz* - did you actually disable turbo to limit CPU frequency? 
 https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/core_i5/i5-8400 lists the max 1-core turbo at 4.0 GHz, the max all-cores turbo at 3.8 GHz.   *and highest vector flag AVX2.* - you left that out of your command line for the example.  Did you really just use `-mavx2` without `-mfma`?  Prefer `-march=native` or `-march=skylake` for your CPU, or `-march=x86-64-v3` for AVX2+FMA+BMI2 with generic tuning.

Comment: (Overall, good self-answered Q&A, though.  The cumbersome computational work is slow enough to keep one core from coming close to saturating read bandwidth, like would happen on that CPU for simply summing an array or a dot product of two arrays.  Or it would if GCC was better at optimizing simple sums by using multiple accumulators: [What makes numpy.sum faster than an optimized (auto-vectorized) C loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77823375) shows GCC leaving a lot of performance on the table with latency bottlenecks)

Comment: @PeterCordes could be, honestly I don't remember what my line of reasoning was. Anyway if OP is fine with using `auto` everywhere more power to him. It's just that I don't see the point of using it and then having to `static_cast` everywhere to make sure the types are right anyway (I might be bias because i REALLY hate dynamically typed languages so not seeing the type clearly specified rubs me kinda the wrong way)

Comment: @JohnDoe: Implicit conversion based on `double tmp = *ptr;` is often not desirable and can be an accident, although that's what I would have written.  This `static_cast` style makes the conversions explicit.  For example Rust would require you to write `let tmp = *ptr as double`, never allowing implicit conversions even between integer types, so maybe that's influenced by a modern style of preferring types on the right?  So I can see some value in that, but not some of the other ways the OP uses `auto`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I actually compiled it later with `-march=native` with the result being unchanged.

Comment: @JohnDoe Imagine I have 5000 lines of code, peppered with calls to a particular function. Then one day, I change the signature of the function, and suddenly the types are all different. Then I have to comb my 5000 lines of code, changing the types everywhere. This is avoided by the Always Auto style, using which I can just change the interface, and the rest of the code is instantly savvy. Moreover, it helps a _lot_ with cross-platform readiness.

Comment: Unchanged from what?  There's different asm with `-mavx2` (no FMA) vs. `-march=skylake` (with FMA), which should make a difference for low thread counts where you aren't memory bound.  You should put your actual optimization options into the GCC command in the last section of this answer.  I looked at that first to see how you were building, and saw it didn't have any `-m` options; it wasn't until later I noticed something about AVX2 in another part of your question, so putting your actual options there would be a big improvement.

Comment: @JohnDoe It becomes a philosophical question: do I care that it's an 8 bit int with a certain alignment etc or do I simply want a type which has certain characteristics e.g. it is arithmetic, can be default constructed, can be passed in certain functions etc.? Naming and choosing types are cognitive loads which must be reduced to concentrate on the more essential aspects of coding. So that code can stay abstract and we can still let the compiler do the necessary concretizations. This paradigm requires you to often use explicit casting at points where it is _important_ to manually choose types.

Comment: Your example is also missing `#include <vector>`.  It doesn't compile on my Arch GNU/Linux system without that, with g++13.2.1.

Comment: Also it needs the user to specify a size, but I don't know what size you tested with, and there's no default.  And you still haven't fixed the build command to include `-march=native` when you fixed the missing header.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think now it should have all the information. With "result being unchanged", I meant that the speed-up diagram I've posted here looked the same after using the arch and fast math flags.

Comment: I tried it on my own system (i7-6700k Skylake 4c8t at 3.9GHz with DDR4-2666, G++ 13.2.1).  With `OMP_NUM_THREADS=2` or higher, it bottlenecks on DRAM bandwidth at about 25 to 27 GiB/s.  But yeah, `-march=native -mno-fma` only slightly slows down the `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` case, from 15.4 to 15.1 GiB/s.  Probably the bottleneck is shuffle throughput (1/clock on port 5) rather than ports 0 / 1 which can run FP FMA/add/mul and `blendps`.  (Ice Lake adds a second shuffle unit on port 1 which can handle some shuffles.)

Comment: @NitinMalapally I guess it depends on the application, I work on embedded systems with very low power devices where a couple of bytes difference might mean the software will or will not fit on them so I'm probably more strict about memory alignment and memory usage than most. Probably for math stuff is not so important

Answer (score 6):

I would like to offer my own answer. Firstly, I noticed that a roof is being struck at a certain speed-up. The function of interest is a streaming function i.e. it makes no use of caches. This means the DRAM bandwidth will end up being the bottleneck. Using this as roof, we have the following image.

[image]

Another effect we see is the non-linear strong scaling. I think (but am not sure) that what we see here is caused by powerful vector units and pre-fetchers; as the core count increases, we very quickly saturate the bandwidth, which means that further increase in core count comes with resource contention.

[image]

What causes me to doubt this theory is the fact that the peak performance is not quite as close to the DRAM bandwidth as I'd liked to have seen. But this could be because of the OpenMP reduction...

Comment: Good self answer! Such a behaviour is frequent for memory-bound codes. Saturating 100% of the DRAM is generally not possible (90-95% is generally very good for reads). There are several possible explanation for the scalability at 6 core based on the exact hardware. On your hardware, the most probable one is that the accesses are a bit more random due to more cores. The prefetching is likely less efficient because of that (AFAIK Intel CPUs tends to reduce the prefetching window when there are a lot of requests so to increase the efficiency of non-contiguous reads).

Comment: Another possible explanation is that there are significantly more read misses reducing the prefetching efficiency (some cache lines may need to be reloaded twice due to conflict misses). You can check this hypothesis by analysing low-level hardware counters, especially the one of the L3 cache. Note this is not easy for beginners.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71911346/12939557) provides some insights about such an issue but it is for writes and the problem is critical because of the strides (while data are mostly contiguous here). Non temporal loads may help but results are generally rather disappointing in this case (AFAIK they are even basic loads on many CPUs)...

Comment: For the DRAM hypothesis, you can check the latency of DRAM operations if available on your CPU (I doubt there is a counter on your CPU for that though), especially the different kind of latencies sources (other than the CAS one).

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thank you for the new angle. Yes, cache conflicts could be another reason why I'm seeing this behaviour. If multiple cores start pre-fetching, we could have conflicts due to associativity, which is once again a form of contention. Also, I completely agree with you that detecting cache conflicts is very hard.